# Input type for cordinates in laravel form collective

Tags: laravel, maps, laravel-form

i have a form for storing restaurants info

```
        {!! Form::open(['action' => 'RestaurantsController@store','method'=>'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'])!!}
        <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('name','Name')}}
        {{Form::text('name','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Insert here'])}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('hours','Hours')}}
                {{Form::text('hours','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Insert here'])}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('contact','Contact')}}
                        {{Form::text('contact','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Insert here'])}}
                        </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('payment','Payment')}}
                        {{Form::text('payment','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Insert here'])}}
                        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('menu','Menu')}}
                {{Form::textarea('menu',null,['id'=>'menu','placeholder'=>'Insert here','name'=>'menu'])}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('description','Description')}}
                        {{Form::textarea('description',null,['id'=>'description','placeholder'=>'Insert here','name'=>'description'])}}
                </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::file('cover_image')}}
        </div>
        {{-- {{Form::hidden('_method','POST')}} --}}
        {{Form::submit('submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','type'=>'submit','id'=>'submit'])}}

        {!! Form::close() !!} 


        </div>

        </body>


        </html>

        @endsection
```

I need to store restaurants longitude and lattitude how do i go about that.This is the lattitude migration  that i added after creating the restaurants form

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('restaurants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->decimal('lat', 10, 7); 
        });
    }
```

I need to store the restaurants cordinates so that i can query those that are nearby to the user you can help with this too

Comment: Just use `$table->geometry('positions');`

Comment: what about the input form?

Comment: No idea about that, but it's possible you'd need some parsing of strings.